# Cannot get out of grub

Tags: grubrescue

```
Grub>
Possible commands are:
    
{ commands......}

Grub> ls
(Proc) (hd0) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt2)
Grub> ls (hdx,y)
Device (null): filesystem type ext* - last modification time 2020-11-05    06:55:31 Thursday, UUID 1995259e-0866-4c30-a45c-e9c5b4d28945 - partition start at 525315kiB - Total size 976236544kiB
Grub> sudo 
Error: can't find command 'sudo'.
```

Comment: `sudo` is definetely not in the list of possible commands. To leave just type `exit` and hit `Enter`.